# WPF validation - ValidatesOnTargetUpdated

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox, validationrules

I have a number of textboxes in a WPF app on which I have set up some validation.

On load the app deserialises a class onto which the WPF window's controls are bound.

I have a ValidationRule that (for example) tests that a file exists.  If I don't set ValidatesOnTargetUpdated then the corresponding TextBox validates when I change the (bound) Text Property and I see the (default) red border appear and a Tooltip (`{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}`) displaying the error message.

I want the controls to validate on binding rather than on propertychanged so I have set the ValidatesOnTargetUpdated to true and can see the validationRule firing when debugging.

My problem is that the (default) ValidationTemplate is ignored when `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` despite the ValidationRule firing.

I can see the Tooltip - it appears with the correct error message but the border doesn't show as Red; this seems to be ignored.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/2fade1e0-6d37-4c6d-ac34-48b3c1062e27). I believe the part that pertains to your situation is:

> **Problem: The Error Template is not
>   Displayed when a Page is Loaded**
>
> This is by design, since one could
>   assume that the user doesn't want to
>   see error messages before he/she made
>   any mistakes, but sometimes one needs
>   this functionality. So, the
>   ValidatesOnTargetUpdated property was
>   introduced on the ValidationRule
>   class; by setting it to true, one sees
>   the validation result immediately.
>   However, there is one caveat: you must
>   make sure that you set the DataContext
>   after the page is initialized; this
>   would be either in the constructor
>   after the generated comment line that
>   says that initialization code should
>   go there, or in the Loaded event. If
>   you want to set the DataContext in
>   XAML, you find a solution for this
>   problem here:
>   http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/navigating-from-object-to-object/
>
> However, I hear this will be fixed in
>   WPF 4.0.

EDIT:

A more permanent link can be found [here](http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/using-validation-errortemplate/).

Comment: OK, thanks for that - makes sense to me.  Thing is I am not sure how else to do this.  Is there another way of forcing validation after binding?

Comment: Scratch that request - I decided to do my own validation on the data class and bind an additional control to indicate validity

Comment: You mentioned that there is a solution if you want to set the DataContext in XAML.  I do not see anything in the link provided that shows how to get around the DataContext being set before the InitializeComponent is called (which is what happens when I use XAML to set the DataContext).  Can you provide any more clarity on this?

Comment: @KevinKalitowski - That portion of text was quoted from the forum post link earlier. But in the wpfglue link, it looks like they actually set the DataContext is code-behind also. So I'm not sure you could set the DataContext in XAML in this case.